# Changing IP address of Apache server using PHP statically

Tags: shell-script, shell, arch-linux, php, apache-httpd

I want to statically assign the IP address of my Arch linux using php. I want to change the IP by using netmask,interface,broadcast,address & gateway. The user puts up the values into a html page. The html page posts the data to the PHP page. I want to change the ip using this data. ho to do this?? please help me on this.

Can Files be used?

I was thinking of writing directly into the rc.conf using files!!...will this work and how??.. I have my arch linux up with apache & php..any of the help is appreciate.

Comment: If you are going to roll edits back, at least have the courtesy to improve upon the edited version in the process...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change IP permanently you need to modify values in `rc.conf`. After that modification you need to restart `network` service. You can do that in two ways:

```
/etc/rc.d/network restart
```

or

```
rc.d restart network
```

To modify `rc.conf` and restart service you need root privileges. As running apache as root isn't good idea I would recommend creating some wrapper that is started using sudo for restarting services and modifying `rc.conf`.

PHP script -> start shell script `sudo ./modify-network IP NETMASK GW`

Sudo entry for this should be in format:

```
www ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/modify-network
```

Remember to filter your input in PHP script. Check if IP number is real IP not `rc.conf`-injection ;) like `192.168.0.100"\nDAEMONS=(!apache)`.

And remember to redirect user to new address after you change it (when user press "Change IP" button, post data, do some javascript `sleep 1` and `window.location.href = 'http://NEW_IP/';`

You could also use SELinux to add more security to this solution...